# What is the distribution of $Y$ if $Y$ satisfies $P(Y=X_j \mid (X_1,\ldots,X_n)) = \frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. with common distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, *and assume $X_i \neq X_j$ almost surely for $i\neq j.$*

Consider now the random variable $Y$ which satisfies that $Y \mid (X_1,\ldots,X_n) \sim \mu_n$, where $\mu_n= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{X_j}$. In other words $Y$ is drawn from the sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ uniformly (i.e. $P(Y=X_j \mid (X_1,\ldots,X_n)) = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $j=1,\ldots,n$).

**My question is: What is the distribution of $Y$?**

Intuitively the distribution would definitely depend on $\mu$. My guess would be that $Y \sim \mu$ but I am not sure.

I have tried the following for $y \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$
P(Y=y) = P(Y=X_i =y \mid X_i=y) P(X_i=y) = P(Y=X_i \mid X_i = y) \mu(y).
$$
If this holds, then one would need to compute $P(Y=X_i \mid X_i = y)$. Here I was thinking maybe Bayes' rule might come in handy but I can't quite make it work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try calculating the CDF? P(Y < y), Y will be less than y with probability 1 if all X_i < y, and with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$ if n-1 of X_1 to X_n is less than y and so on.

Comment: Things may go wrong with your setup if $P(X_i=X_j)>0$ for some $i\not=j$, i.e. if $X_i$ does not have a continuous distribution

Comment: @Henry Yes I forgot to state this as an assumption. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P\big(Y\in A\big)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}P\big(Y\in A\,\big|\,X=x\big)d\mu^n\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{j=1}^nP\big(Y\in A,Y=X_j\,\big|\,X=x\big)d\mu^n\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{j=1}^nP\big(X_j\in A,Y=x_j\,\big|\,X=x\big)d\mu^n\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{j=1}^nI_A(x_j)P\big(Y=x_j\,\big|\,X=x\big)d\mu^n\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nI_A(x_j)d\mu^n\\
&=\mu(A)
\end{align}